# MongoDB doesn't install on the preferred installation disk Windows

Tags: mongodb, installation

I'm trying to install MongoDB version 5.0.1 on my Windows 10 machine. I want it to install in my D drive, so I've tried Custom installing it and choosing the appropriate paths in the D drive. For reference, the installation location I chose is `D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\`.

However, when I click the final install button, it always brings up the following message:
[image]

This makes no sense since I never involved the C drive at all (even the msi installer is in the D drive downloads folder). That dialog box doesn't let me do anything on it; it implies that

The reason I'm not using C drive is because it's strictly off limits as dictated by this computer's owner.

I've downloaded the installer multiple times as well as modified my local folder structure. Anyone know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need the installer. Download the `zip` package and unzip to your disk.

Optionally add the mongo binary folder to your `%PATH%` variable, that's it.

You can create a Mongo service with single command like this:

```
"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\mongod.exe" --config c:\MongoDB\config\mongodb.cfg --install
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because this .msi package sends into the `c:\Windows\Installer\` for the uninstalling ability after install, and it sends all 484mb package as it is. It's 100 IQ development...

I found only one way how to fix this 100 IQ dev issue:

1. Extract all files from the `msi` package by this command in the `cmd`

`msiexec /a "d:\mongodb-windows-x86_64-6.0.5-signed.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="d:\mongodb\files"`

2. The you will get all files with a new msi installer which is about 1.9Mb instead of 484Mb.